# Email This Plugin for Chrome

Tags: email, google-chrome, plugins

Firefox has this massively useful plugin called [EmailThis](http://lazyrussian.com/my-projects/email-this-firefox-extension/) by LazyRussian. It allows you to right-click on a page and just kick off your webmail compose page and email it.

But...Firefox has become a dog, so I now vastly prefer Chrome.

Is there something similar to EmailThis for Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with JMD on slow extension support for chrome. If you are looking for extension support, you can always download dev version of chrome. It has preety good extension support already but it still have to come to regular users.

Until extensions are developed for chrome, you can use BookMarklets. (Bookmarklet is a java script code which sits in your bookmark toolbar and when clicked can accomplish mostly same thing as extensions. No dedicated UI components like extensions but it works.)

If you are using GMail for your main email client, you can refer to http://contrapants.org/blog/2005/07/gmailthis.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I share your pain regarding extensions in Chrome.  Unfortunately, you'll find that support for extensions in Chrome lags far behind their ubiquity in FF.  In the searching I did I found that a large portion of the would-be-Chrome users are still using FF because they can't readily install, first and foremost, AdBlock Plus.  Unfortunately, an extension like AdBlock Plus runs right counter to Google's main stream of revenue: selling ads.  Thus, [imho]I suspect that extension support in Chrome is slow in delivery because of Google's reluctance to enable something which directly conflicts with their business model.[/imho]

Comment: I would go so far as to say that, while I do periodically use Chrome, I might make the final switch to Google's browser if I could have just that one extension.

Comment: @jmd, there are actually extensions out there that mimic AdBlock, including a beta of ABP for Chrome itself.  I don't think it has anything to do with their model, since other than techies, no one even knows about ABP. 

But yeah, no having EmailThis is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Windows OS? Since Chrome won't automate it, you could use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do it for you..?